# How can I loop associative array respectively

Tags: php, arrays, iteration, associative-array, nested-loops

I have following associative array:

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 268
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 125
        [1] => 258
        [2] => 658
        [3] => 128
        [4] => 987
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 123
        [1] => 258
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 168
    )
 )
```

I need the following result as string.

```
   268
   125258658128987
   123258
   168
```

What I have tried so far;

```
    <?php
    //consider my array is in $array variable
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)
    {
     foreach ($array[$i] as $res)
     {
     echo $res . '<br/>';
     }
     }
     ?>
```

But unfortunately I am getting each numbers in a new line. 
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `echo` the `<br />` outside the `foreach` loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)
{
    foreach ($array[$i] as $res) {
        echo $res;
    }
    echo '<br />';   //<-- Put this outside the foreach loop
}
```

---

Or another option, you can use `foreach` and `implode` for a simpler approach

```
foreach ($array as $value)
{
    echo implode('',$value);
    echo '<br />';
}
```

Doc: [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)